# Git PS1 & Bash Subshell Issue (Windows vs Linux)

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, dotfiles

After trawling google, the bash manpage and other questions here on SO, I have found similar posts but I have failed to determine the cause of this particular issue.

I have installed git-prompt.sh locally. All is good in the bash --login shell. It really is a good thing on both Windows and Linux.

However, as soon as I execute a bash subshell (e.g so that I can temporarily modify my environment etc) I get the error:

```
$ ... <in/out of repos and all good>
$ bash
bash: __git_ps1: command not found
```

This problem does *not* happen on Windows.

Something to note is that I have my dotfiles setup via git. For this reason I can run my configuration on both windows and linux and they both have exactly the same git-prompt.sh file.

- Windows 10 git==2.19.2.windows.1 bash==4.4.19(2)-release
- Arch Linux git==2.19.2 bash==4.4.23(1)-release

Both are fresh OS installs.

My best *guess* so far is that different shell interaction semantics are executed when operating under windows rather than linux. I have experimented with various bash invocations (--login, --norc ie so I can manually set stuff) etc. There are 3 reasons for this suspicion:

1. This error *looks like* the kind of error we get when we forget to export a variable/parameter.
2. Both "/etc/profile.d" sources are different on each platform. Some contain git support, and perhaps this is contributing to the previous reason.
3. My bash-fu was good ~10+ years ago, now I am rusty.

One thing I know for sure is that the first login bash ("sub")shell works perfectly on both platforms.

Any ideas, feedback or pointers?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Looks like you defined but didn't export the `__git_ps1` function in your parent shell, but *are* exporting a `PS1` that refers to that function... so child processes get the `PS1` that only works with the function, but don't get the function itself. Putting `export -f __git_ps1` alongside the assignment should fix the issue, or moving the function declaration from your `.bash_profile` to your `.bashrc`.

Comment: BTW, for future reference, our sister site [unix.se] is generally a better fit for questions about dotfiles (or otherwise interactive shell setup, vs software development proper).

Comment: Where are you sourcing `git_prompt.sh`? You should probably do it in `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile` or some other file that is only used for login shells, rather than any interactive shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess Unix & Linux will tolerate the Windows reference!  ;-)

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the suggestion. I have implemented in .bashrc as forwarded from .bash_profile as the initial shell is a "--login" shell. As I understand this is a standard practice.

Comment: Not really. It's better to set `PS1` on demand in `.bashrc` rather than cluttering your environment with it, because no other program aside from an interactive shell cares about its value.

Comment: (OK, other shells might care about `PS1`, but considering you are almost certainly relying on `bash`-specific features in your prompt, having a different shell inherit such a prompt won't work as expected.)

Comment: @chepner Thanks for your help. For my previous comment to you, my understanding is as per [https://www.stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others/](https://www.stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others/)

Comment: I want to set up git-prompt in my .bash_profile and not .bashrc because it is slow, and I don't want to have to wait each time something creates an interactive sub-shell.  I also had to add export -f __git_sequencer_status and __git_eread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The issue was due to a comibination of (2) above (i.e. indirect different versions of the prompt) and bad quoting of a regular expression by myself in a guard.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your `PS1` (or something performing a similar function) is exported, but your `__git_ps1` function itself is not.

To export the function, use `export -f __git_ps1`.

Comment: That was what I thought in (1) above, but alas it didn't work. All of the __git_* functions are not exported.